# Latex weird footnote numbering

Tags: latex, pdflatex

[image]

[image]

There are weird footnote numbers that I did not intend to generate. I added only two footnotes, but there are footnotes number 2 and 4 that I did not write.

I cannot figure out the solution. Did anyone experience the same problem or know the solution?

The below is the Latex code of this. Even if I don't use any of usepackage options, the problem still happens.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
blablablalba\footnotemark
\\
\\
\\
\footnote{firstfootnote}
\\
\\
\\
wordswordswords\footnotemark
\\
\\
\\
\footnote{secondfootnote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: adding footnote numbering does not solve the problem.

`\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
blablablalba\footnotemark[1]
\\
\\
\\
\footnote[1]{firstfootnote}
\\
\\
\\
wordswordswords\footnotemark[2]
\\
\\
\\
\footnote[2]{secondfootnote}

\end{document}`

Comment: Why are you using `\footnotemark` at all and not just the footnotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution.

Using \footnote was the problem. Changing it to \footnotetext solves the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
blablablalba\footnotemark[1]
\\
\\
\\
\footnotetext[1]{firstfootnote}
\\
\\
\\
wordswordswords\footnotemark[2]
\\
\\
\\
\footnotetext[2]{secondfootnote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just curious: why are you using such a complicated construct?

Answer (score 0):

The additional numbers are added by using both `\footnotemark` and `\footnote`. To avoid this problem, only use `\footnote{...}` where you want your footnotemarker to be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
blablablalba\footnote{firstfootnote}


wordswordswords\footnote{secondfootnote}

\end{document}
```